# Where do you add a TFS 2017 (on prem) user to be able to modify test suites?

Tags: tfs, administration

I'm a TFS project administrator.
I'd like to add a member of the team to whatever group is needed so that they can manage test plans/export test suites and the like.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is just adding the user to **Contributors** group for a team project, which will have the **manage test plans and test suites** task.

[image]

> **Note:** Stakeholders cannot create or manage test plans. You must have at least **Basic** access.

If you don't want to add the user to default Contributors group in project, you could also directly assign permission to him or by creating a new group, permissions can be given at Project level and at [Area path level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/permissions#nbspnbspnbsparea-path-object-level)(*Manage test plans & suites permission*).

More details please refer: **[Default manual testing permissions and access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/manual-test/manual-test-permissions)**

---

**Update**

work- Areas- Right click area - select Security- Contributor
[image]

Comment: Hey PatrickLu-MSFT, I don't have the "manage test plan & test suites" option for the Contribute role. How do I add it?

Comment: @Irwin Try to use **Area path level** permission, there should be a **Manage test plans**  **Manage test suites** for contribute group. Add a screenshot in update reply for your reference.

Comment: Hi @Irwin any update on this issue, have you tried my solution to assign user manage test plans and test suits permission at **area level**? Did it work?

Comment: Hey @Patrick, I saw the permissions set but my user, who is in the contributor group, still doesn't have access. Here's a screen shot of the setup: https://imgur.com/RJAZxPJ

Comment: @Irwin What's the error info when the user try to modify test suites? In TFS **deny trumps allow**, have you double check all other groups the user belongs to? Make sure there is no one group set the Manage test plans/ Manage test suites `deny` or `not set`. Besides, Test Mange is **not a free feature** in TFS, make sure you have paid for that user or the user already with a kind of Visual Studio subscriptions which Test Manager extension is included. Detail kind of subscriptions info please refer this  link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-testmanager-web#pricing

Comment: Does it matter that I'm using TFS on-prem? (2017 update 3)